# How can I test mouse detection on canvas (JavaScript) when the canvas's height exceeds the screen's height (when the scroll bar appears)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouseenter, mouseclick-event

I can test mouse coordinates on canvas when there is no scroll bar with:

```
var mx = evt.clientX - canvas.offsetX
var my = evt.clientY - canvas.offsetY
```

However, when I scroll down the webpage, and I reposition the mouse the coordinates are skewed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Dear Li Ming, do you feel as though my answer was answer helpful to you?

Comment: Yes, your response helped me indeed. :)

Comment: On Stack Overflow when an answer fully solves your problem, it's customary to mark it as accepted by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of it. This gives reputation to both the asker and the answerer. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, ok. I am new to Stack Overflow, and didn't know about that feature. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No worries, it's just part of learning the site :)

Comment: Hey Maximillian, I took a look at your site; it looks very professional if I do say so myself. You see, I want to study Computer Science someday as well. You've inspired me, and I thank you for that.

Comment: Thanks! It's an exciting field to be a part of. I particularly enjoy web development myself.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister would it be too much to ask for you to review my site? My homepage: bit.ly/1Xd4gdi (which is just a simple site made with Jekyll). My actual site: bit.ly/1TitBjC (title: Webucation, it is a site that teaches the basics of web development with the web programming languages of HTML, CSS, and JS). I have a survey up on both sites to get user feedback. Feel free to judge it harshly, for I want to improve the site. Thank you for your answers, and thanks in advance.

Comment: I just gave your site a quick look and here is my review (it's biased by my experience so take it with a grain of salt). Focusing on your actual site since your Jekyll theme looks great to me. Having autoplaying audio on a web page is a huge no-no unless the audio is the main focus of a page (i.e. the entire page is a video, the entire page is a digital art piece with sound, etc.) On the front page the nav menu to the left looks great. The display box in the middle with the languages looks a bit weird with the indentation, I would consider putting the 3 languages side by side.

Comment: The page transition makes the site feel a bit sluggish in my opinion and is unneeded. If you decide to keep it I would lower the duration a lot so it is less than half a second or shorter. On a wide monitor your Youtube videos get really stretched out horizontally, so I would give them (basically the whole content column with the videos and text) a max-width so they don't get stretched out all too far. I'm not a huge fan of the logo just because I don't feel like the text stands out enough against the black brackets. I would consider redoing the logo so the brackets are outside the text.

Comment: I like the circle pattern on the right hand side but the circles are not lined up in a perfect grid (they are a few pixels off from each other). They also have some jaggies. I would consider recreating the image in a vector program like Inkscape or Adobe Illustrator, or for maximum geek points write some javascript that draws it to a canvas and randomizes the colors each time (ok that would be totally overkill, but just an idea I came up with). Finally I would write some media queries so the site's layout shows up great on a mobile phone (or other device with a narrow screen).

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Thank you for your criticisms, they are of much help to me. This will help me in the future as well as improve my site currently.

Comment: Hopefully I haven't been too harsh. The website is easy to navigate as it is, and I really like the way the menu is laid out. Also hopefully some of what I said helps, and I think it's awesome that you are helping others learn web development!

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Your input was exactly what I needed. Now I know what I can do over these next couple months. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to test the mouse's position on the canvas (and not the mouse's position on the screen). For that, `evt.offsetX` and `evt.offsetY` are sufficient even when there is a scrollbar.

Please see the **working live demo** here, and open your JS console and you will be able to see the cursor's coordinates relative to the canvas:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];

canvas.onmousemove = function(evt) {
    var mx = evt.offsetX;
    var my = evt.offsetY;
    console.log(mx, my);
}
```

```html
<canvas height="800" width="200" style="border: solid black 1px"></canvas>
```